# About all kinds of Callback(s) in CGLIB

Tags: cglib

We know that CGLIB provides several Callback implementations, with the most useful one of MethodInterceptor. However, how about other ones(FixedValue, Dispatcher, LazyLoader, NoOp, ProxyRefDispatcher) ? I browse the API document but can not get useful information.  Can anyone show how and when to use these Callbacks in what scenarios ?  I read the related code in Spring but I am still puzzled.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a summary of all callbacks (and more) in this blog article: 
http://mydailyjava.blogspot.no/2013/11/cglib-missing-manual.html